# How to sort by a calculated column in Supabase?

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

is it possible to sort a db query using the supabase api on a computed value?

something like:

```
await supabase
  .from('drives')
  .select('distance / time AS speed')
  .order('speed', { ascending: false })
```

(yes i know i could call a custom postgres function)

Comment: You can probably encapsulate this in an RPC. Or generate this column directly in the table and then be able to sort this.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL UI editor you can do the following:

```
create function items_count(groups) returns bigint as $$
  select count(*) from items where group_id = $1.id;
$$ stable language sql;
```

And then simply use it like this:

```
await supabase.from("groups").select('*, items(id)').order('items_count');
```

Original source: https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/7875#discussioncomment-3255773